# Как выровнять по центру баннер?

Tags: css

Как сделать чтобы баннер выравнивался по центру, а не с левой стороны.
Использую CMS Xenforo 2

```
<a href="https://123.nl/ru" target="_blank" class="db-ad">
    <img src="http://31.br/images/banner.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Для того чтобы решить вашу проблему, объясните как именно вы хотите видеть конечный результат, и приложите ваши попытки совершить данное дело. На данный момент вариантов решения данной проблемы много, начиная от float, flexbox, заканчивая CSS GRID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* выравнивание по вертикали */
  justify-content: center; /* выравнивание по горизонтали */
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="header" role="banner">
  <a href="https://123.nl/ru" target="_blank" class="db-ad">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/50">
  </a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Без Вашего примера сложно сказать.

Пример выравнивания https://jsfiddle.net/0s4v7xzg/1/

```
<div class="parent">
<img src="http://mtmurdock.azurewebsites.net/Images/stackoverflow-logo.png" width="150px">
</div>


.parent {
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px
}
img {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: block;
  margin: auto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Флексы всё решают.

```
<style>
.db-ad{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```